# configuration system failed to initialize error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this error that I get on this line is assigned null

```
db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase (CadenaConexion);
```

the CadenaConexion brings data

It is worth mentioning that I am migrating an application that was with famework 2 to one that is already made in framework 4

The app.config is this:

```
    <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name = "userSettings" type = "System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name = "Collaboration E.Properties.Settings" type = "System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition = "MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission = "false" />
          <section name = "paths" type = "string" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name = "Inte" connectionString = "Server = DESAOPER; Database = eDocInteDB; User = usr_InteDB; Pwd = G0rd1t @ 5314;" providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name = "Prod" connectionString = "Server = SRVECOM; Database = eDocProdDB; User = Corporate Dbo; Pwd = Record" providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key = "Integration" value = "Inte" />
        <add key = "Production" value = "Prod" />
      </appSettings>
      <paths>
        <add key = "File Path" value = "% ROUTE%" />
        <add key = "Delimiter" value = "
    | "/>
        <add key = "URLCSDSAT" value = "ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/agti_service_ftp/verifica_comprobante_ftp/CSD.txt" />
        <add key = "URLFOLSAT" value = "ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/agti_service_ftp/verifica_comprobante_ftp/FoliosCFD.txt" />
      </paths>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns = "urn: schemas-microsoft-com: asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name = "DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken = "8fb06cb64d019a17" culture = "neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion = "0.0.0.0-2.10.0.0" newVersion = "2.10.0.0" />
            <! - <assemblyIdentity name = "Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken = "31bf3856ad364e35" culture = "neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion = "0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion = "1.0.0.0" /> ->
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <userSettings>
        <Collaboration E.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name = "Password" serializeAs = "String">
            <value />
          </setting>
        </ Collaboration E. Properties.Settings>
      </userSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Everything is in c #, I have no experience in windows forms

greetings and thanks

Comment: Most likely, something is wrong with your xml config. Remove things out of it, start with blank. Than add sections one by one. You will find which one is the problem. I can tell that your `<paths>` sits outside `userSettings`. This could be it

Comment: ok thanks the error don´t apper anymore, it was a conflict with:                    
       <paths>
        <add key = "File Path" value = "% ROUTE%" />
        <add key = "Delimiter" value = "
    | "/>
        <add key = "URLCSDSAT" value = "ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/agti_service_ftp/verifica_comprobante_ftp/CSD.txt" />
        <add key = "URLFOLSAT" value = "ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/agti_service_ftp/verifica_comprobante_ftp/FoliosCFD.txt" />
      </paths> I commented this lines

Comment: I think, your `paths` were simply outside of `<userSettings>`. Try moving it there. Should work

Comment: it´s true thanks again